# How to read parameters from a file within a Jenkins pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a pipeline and it's run for three different branches(`dev`/`uat`/`master`). Some parameters change for each branch hence they are hardcoded for each environment resulting in three `Jenkinsfile`s (one for each environment).

My second solution is to have three different properties file based on environment. A single Jenkins job will trigger the Jenkins jobs but based on branch name (which I will pick up from GitHub webhook trigger).

My `Jenkinsfile` has an environment variable whose assignment looks like below:

**myJenkinsJob.jenkinsfile**

```
serviceAccountName = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "awk -F= '{$1 ~ /serviceAccountName/ ; gsub($1"=","") ; print}' dev.properties").trim()
```

`dev.properties` file looks like this:

```
serviceAccountName=abc@def.com
```

This evaluates to the value mentioned in the properties file. `serviceAccountName=abc@def.com`.

Does anyone has any better/easier alternative? Some plugin which can read the parameters passed in file without going through all `sh` commands for assignments in environment/parameters block?

Comment: Re "_Some parameters change for each branch hence they are hardcoded for each environment resulting in three jenkinsfiles_". Does that really mean you never ever merge one branch into an other?

Comment: hi Gerald, We do merge the branches. I have three files in each branch, they are named like myJenkinsJob_dev.jenkinsfile, myJenkinsJob_uat.jenkinsfile, myJenkinsJob_prod.jenkinsfile. We merge feature branch to dev to uat to prod in that order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use one Jenkinsfile for all branches and add an init stage to setup your variables according the branch name, using the `BRANCH_NAME` environment variable :

```
stage ('Init') {
    steps {
        script {
            switch(env.BRANCH_NAME) {
                case 'dev':
                    serviceAccountName = 'dev@def.com'
                    break
                case 'uat':
                    serviceAccountName = 'uat@def.com'
                    break
                case 'master':
                    serviceAccountName = 'master@def.com'
                    break
                default:
                    error('Unexpected branch name')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use a properties file you can use the [readFile](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace) syntax or use a YAML and use the [readYaml](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readyaml-read-yaml-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text) which can be easier to parse the retrieved value.

Example :

`dev.yml` file can look like this :

```
service-account-name: abc@def.com
```

And then using `readYaml` in your pipeline :

```
def devData = readYaml file: 'dev.yml' 
def serviceAccountName = devData.service-account-name
```

For all the environment variables Jenkins supplies see the page `https://your.jenkins.host:port/env-vars.html`.